# Import dll which is buit in vc++ into C# code

Tags: c#

I am having my dll which is built in VC++ and that created dll was used in one Visual Basic application. Now I want to use that dll and import it into my c# application. But when I am trying add reference of that dll, I got an error of

> dll could not be added. please make sure file is accessible, and that is valid assembly or COM component.

I have implemnted below code in my c# apllication and now I want to use tssfor.dll. But from where or how can I add that dll? Please help me out.

using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Web;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DLLTest

{

```
public class Class1

{

    [DllImport("tssfor.dll")]

    public static extern int tssfor(string Infile, long l1, string tmpfile, long l2, string Lookfile, long l16, string RainFile,
        long l18, string affiliate, long l6, string Prodname, long l20, string version, long l7, string Vernum, long l19, string Country, long l17,
        string metric, long l15, string Projnam, Int32 l8, string Projnum, long l9, string projloc, long l10, string projco, long l11, string projeng,
        long l12, string projdate, long l13, string projnote, long l14, string Rainloc, long l3, string RainLat, long l4, string RainLong, long l5, Single elevft,
        Single areareal, long Varint, long Numsv, long ptstor, Single loadreal, Single sg, Single ps, Single pct, Single vs, Single stor, Single storq, Single split,
        Single dwf, Single intensv, Single pflow, Single ptss);

    public void tss(string Infile, long l1, string tmpfile, long l2, string Lookfile, long l16, string RainFile,
        long l18, string affiliate, long l6, string Prodname, long l20, string version, long l7, string Vernum, long l19, string Country, long l17,
        string metric, long l15, string Projnam, Int32 l8, string Projnum, long l9, string projloc, long l10, string projco, long l11, string projeng,
        long l12, string projdate, long l13, string projnote, long l14, string Rainloc, long l3, string RainLat, long l4, string RainLong, long l5, Single elevft,
        Single areareal, long Varint, long Numsv, long ptstor, Single loadreal, Single sg, Single ps, Single pct, Single vs, Single stor, Single storq, Single split,
        Single dwf, Single intensv, Single pflow, Single ptss)
    {
        tssfor(Infile, l1, tmpfile, l2, Lookfile, l16, RainFile, l18, affiliate, l6, Prodname, l20,version, l7, Vernum, l19, Country, l17, metric, l15,
            Projnam, l8, Projnum, l9, projloc, l10, projco, l11, projeng, l12, projdate, l13, projnote, l14, Rainloc, l3, RainLat, l4, RainLong, l5, elevft,
            areareal, Varint, Numsv, ptstor, loadreal, sg, ps, pct, vs, stor, storq, split, dwf, intensv, pflow, ptss);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: [How to: Call Native DLLs from Managed Code Using PInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55d3thsc.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for referring this link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An unmanaged DLL cannot be added as a reference to a .net project. Instead you need to use some form of interop. Common choices include:

1. P/invoke
2. COM
3. C++/CLI

Comment: How Can I do this? Will you please help me some more in this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It kind of depends which one you want to do. You didn't supply any details of the DLL you have so there's no way I could recommend which option to choose. You asked a broad question about why you could not add the DLL as a reference. You should do some reading around the subject before proceeding.

Comment: I have used P/Invoke method to call function of that dll. I have also registered using regsvr32 but i found an error that dll was loaded but entry point is not defined. what should i do to add entry point in it?

Comment: Why do you expect regsvr32 to do anything? Is the DLL a COM server? You appear to be using trial and error.